# Syncing Exchange calendar with SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, exchange-server, exchange

I have a meeting calendar in Exchange which some users use in their Outlook. I want to sync this calendar in Sharepoint (which again can be used by multiple users) so that any change made in Sharepoint will be reflected in that calendar in Exchange and vice versa.
Is it possible?
I have heard that SharePoint only syncs personal calendar and not team calendar.

Answer (score 1):

You can create calendar in SharePoint and then connect with Outlook.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this answer?

Comment: As far as I know this only works with personal calendar. If you have a team calender then it won't be auto synced and instead you will see overlapping calendars i.e. both exchange and sharepoint calendars on top of each other.

Comment: If you create calendar in SharePoint, you can connect this calendar to other users. It can some alternativ version of team calendar.

Comment: Yes but it won't syncs with Exchange calendar which is also shared. There is a feature called "overlay" calendar but this is not what I want.

Comment: I believe what is being suggested by this answer is to create a SharePoint calendar and schedule these meetings on that calendar *instead* of the currently existing Exchange Calendar. I'm guessing, though, that that's not what @FrankMartin is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint:
Create your calendar in SharePoint
Select the calendar tab and Connect to Outlook
In Outlook:
Put the Outlook and sharepoint calendars side by side (not sure this is necessary tbh) and select to veiw the Outlook one in list view
Highlight all data and copy it to your SharePoint calendar

Strangely you should find that you have a two way sync setup between the two. You even start to receive notification of events
I haven't yet tested if you need to leave your Outlook session open for updates to sync but I suspect that you do.